# preselect the select option using php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've a form to be completed to create a `post`. Now after creating that post, if I want to edit it, I'm showing a `select` option in the edit page something like below. (I am using Laravel)

```
<select name="posts">
@foreach($posts as $post)

  <option value="{{$post->id}}"> {{$post->name }} </option>

@endforeach
</select>
```

Now I need to preselect the populated select field with the current `post name`. I have a post id in the URL which I can get know in which post I am in. How can I select the right option without making a duplicate of the same in the options field. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if-else` structure inside the loop.

```
if ( post is equal to the current post ) {
     <option selected="selected" value="{{$post->id}}"> {{$post->name }} </option>
} else {
    <option value="{{$post->id}}"> {{$post->name }} </option>
}
```

The condition depends on you, whether you want to use the post id or the post name to check. (Whatever you have available).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you pass the current post id into the template as `$postId`, you could do something like this:

```
<select name="posts">
@foreach($posts as $post)

    <option value="{{$post->id}}" {{ ($post->id == $postId) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}> {{$post->name }} </option>

@endforeach
</select>
```

Also, since you're using Laravel, a little bit cleaner solution is to use Laravel's Form builder:

```
{{ Form::select('posts', $posts, $postId) }}
```